How to obtain the row sum of the inverse of a symmetrix Toeplitz matrix?
Given a (real) symmetric Toeplitz matrix $A$:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 
a & b & c & \ldots & y & z \\\ 
b & a & b & \ddots & & y \\\
c & b & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots& \vdots \\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & b & c\\\
y & & \ddots & b & a & b\\\ 
z & y & \ldots & c & b & a
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
I would be interested in finding the sum of the values of the $i$-th row of $A^{-1}$, which can also be expressed as:
$$A^{-1}\ \mathbf{1}\ e_i^\intercal$$
where $\mathbf{1}$ is a column vector of all $1$s and $e_i$ a column vector with all $0$s but a $1$ at entry $i$. Equivalently, one can thing of this problem as solving the following system of equations:
$$Ax=\mathbf{1}$$
I don't know if there is any way to obtain these values without explicitly obtaining $A^{-1}$, and, honestly, I also could not find any method for computing $A^{-1}$ given the shape of $A$.

Looking at some small examples, this might actually have an interesting solution.

@DanielV Yes! I agree. Nevertheless, while intuition tells me that there must be some sort of closed-form solution, finding it does not seem pretty straightforward.

The determinant seems to factor into 2 polynomials, one of which also seems to divide the numerator of the sum.
